# Azure List all Instances REST API not returning the mentioned values in response

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

This [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall#responses) gives the List of Instances .

But as mentioned in the document it doesn't give [InstanceViewStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall#instanceviewstatus) values.

**How do we get the InstanceViewStatus while getting the list of instances ?**

Cuz we don't wanna call more number of API's to get this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do we get the InstanceViewStatus while getting the list of
>   instances ?

Based on my knowledge, it is not impossible. They use different REST API.

List all Instances:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01
```

Get InstanceView

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/shuilinux/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/shui?api-version=2017-03-30&$expand=instanceView
```

For get-instanceview, resource group name and VM name are required.

For your scenario, you could use list all instance api to get all VM and vms ID then call get instanceview API. You need a loop.

Just a Rest API, it is not possible.

Comment: I did the same thing . But I was asking that in document it has mentioned that it will give [InstnaceView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/listall#instanceviewstatus) object. But there is no such response value .

Comment: Yes, there is no such value in list all instances API, I suggest you should use get instanceview API.

Comment: `InstnaceView` is one of VM's Definitions, but I think you need use `Get InstanceView` Api to get it.

Comment: Okay mate , I got them in Get InstanceView ... But azure needs to remove that item in response right ?

Comment: `But azure needs to remove that item in response` what do you mean?

Comment: Why they have documented a value which is not available in response ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167149/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-arun-kumar-g-r).